# Lua get table that function is attached to

Tags: lua

Hello I want to get the table that a function is attached to, I can't really find a nice way to explain it but I think i've explained it good enough within the code for. Basically I need to get the table that the function is attached to from another function, without passing in the table.

```
function DrawRect()
    print(debug.getinfo(1).name) -- this gets the name of the function that is invoking DrawRect ('Paint')..
    -- I want to be able to get the table that is attached to this function
    -- So I can do table.x inside this function, and have it print 123
end

local r =  math.random(1, 100)
_G["abc" .. r] = {
    x = 123,
    Paint = function(self)
        DrawRect()
    end
}

_G["abc" .. r]:Paint()
```

Example of the problem i'm trying to solve

This is my current code right now

```
function DrawRect(x,y,w,h)
    draw.DrawRect(x,y,w,h)
end

local Button = {
    Init = function(self)
        self.label = gui.Label("Button")
        self.label:SetPos(10, 5) -- see the position is relative to the Button's position
        self.label:SetColor(255,255,255)
    end,
    
    
    Paint = function(self,x,y,w,h)
        Color(40,40,40)
        DrawRect(x,y,w,h) -- Draws dark background
    end
}
```

As you can see paint has 4 args, x,y,w,h. I want to do away with x,y and only have w,h. I want to achieve this like this.

```
function DrawRect(x,y,w,h)
    local relative_x = parent_table_of_paint.INTERNAL.draw_x
    local relative_y = parent_table_of_paint.INTERNAL.draw_y

    draw.DrawRect(relative_x + x, relative_y + y,w,h)
end

local Button = {
    Init = function(self)
        self.label = gui.Label("Button")
        self.label:SetPos(10, 5) -- see the position is relative to the Button's position
        self.label:SetColor(255,255,255)
    end,
    
    
    Paint = function(self,w,h)
        Color(40,40,40)
        DrawRect(0,0,w,h) -- Draws dark background
    end
}
```

I know you can't see some of the properties in my example, but they are there.

Edit 2:

I am recreating the a frame, "VGUI".
https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/draw.RoundedBox
`draw.RoundedBox( number cornerRadius, number x, number y, number width, number height, table color )`

and as you can see this has the functionality I want
https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/PANEL:Paint

```
local panel = vgui.Create( "DPanel" )
panel:SetSize( 100, 100 )
panel:SetPos( ScrW() / 2 - 50, ScrH() / 2 - 50 )

function panel:Paint( w, h )
    draw.RoundedBox( 8, 0, 0, w, h, Color( 0, 0, 0 ) )
end
```

Comment: There is no way to do what you want.

Comment: what is the problem you're actually trying to solve? https://xyproblem.info

Comment: I thought I defined my problem pretty well, looks like other people got it just fine

Comment: I asked which problem you're actually trying to solve, not what you're asking here. I obviously got that... so how is it helpful or nice in any way to point out other people got you? `debug.getinfo(1).name` is not the function that calls `DrawRect` but `DrawRect` itself btw. you need parameter `2` to get `Paint`

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have your function be called as `_G["abc" .. r]:Paint()` instead of `_G["abc" .. r].Paint()`? Because then it's easy.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes it would. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: @Piglet sorry for rudeness. I have updated my with the actual problem i'm trying to solve

Answer (score 3):

A function is a first class value, so there may be many tables and variables that have a reference to the same function. There is no way for that function to know what those tables and variables are.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you would implement something like that. You don't implement a function that through some magic gets its caller's container so it can access its other values.

`DrawRect` should just draw a rect. If you want to draw a rect somewhere else you should provide that offset through the parameters of `DrawRect`.

I modified your button so it will simply put the buttons `x` and `y` coordinates (if they exist) into `DrawRect`

```
local Button = {
    Init = function(self)
        self.label = gui.Label("Button")
        self.label:SetPos(10, 5) -- see the position is relative to the Button's position
        self.label:SetColor(255,255,255)
    end,
            
    Paint = function(self,w,h)
        Color(40,40,40)
        local x = self.x or 0
        local y = self.y or 0
        DrawRect(x,y,w,h) -- Draws dark background
    end
}
```

That way you can call `Button:Paint(20,30)` to draw a 20 by 30 rectangle at the buttons coordinates. If you want to add an offset, do that outside of `DrawRect`

#### @ Edit 2:

This is something different. The host program will call the `Paint` function.

`vgui.Create( "DPanel" )` will return a new panel instance and the game will add a reference to it to a list. Everytime the gui is updated it will call the Paint functions of all the panels in that list. That's how the function knows width and height of the panel.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but i'm trying to carefully, and strictly recreate gmod's vgui framework. gmod's vgui does this magic. I want to do this so it is easy for people who know vgui to transfer over. yeah I know this is a small thing that could get ignored, but I've gotten so far mimicking the gmod's vgui framework and would like to not break off of it, even if it is something stupid like this. I updated my post so you can see that gmod does this magic, and it is what i am trying to reproduce.

Comment: should be noted that I can't see gmod's code (that is related to this) because it is within the game and of course closed source

Comment: I too have a list of all the panels that, and the panel gets added to the list via vgui.Create("DPanel"), and it loops through the list and calls paint. https://i.imgur.com/FcQ1yfF.png . but i'm confused how the surface.RoundedBox knows that width and height of the panel

Comment: what works the same way? I don't get what you mean. what you said in your edit, I also do within my code and I still don't see a clear way of getting x,y position into the DrawRect function without doing magic

Comment: x and y of what? the panel's? i you have a list of all gui elements that have been created you have access to their coordinates as well.